# How do Vedic fire rituals like Yajnas and agnihotra help the environment?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, yajna, sacrifice

Some texts of hinduism believe that such fire rituals are good sources of attracting clouds and bringing rains.

> annād bhavanti bhūtāni parjanyād anna-sambhavaḥ yajñād bhavati
>   parjanyo yajñaḥ karma-samudbhavaḥ Geeta 3.14
>
> All living bodies subsist on food grains, which are produced from
>   rains. Rains are produced by performance of yajna [sacrifice], and
>   yajna is born of prescribed duties.

I want to know how do these fire rituals help to purify the atmosphere and bring rains ?

Comment: That Gita verse isn't talking about purifying the atmosphere.  It's talking about how doing Yagnas is rewarded with rain through Karma.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan so how do you explain that ?

Comment: It's the law of Karma, good deeds are rewarded with positive things and bad deeds are punished with negative things.

Comment: Yes, Vedic yajnas, Vedic mantras, worship of deities, etc purify the entire area and all the elements where they are done.

Answer (score 4):

**Yagna produces rain(by satisfying gods) which is a necessity for life on earth, so yagna helps ecosystem/environment to sustain itself.**

You should look at context, Sri Krishna is showing importance of doing vedic karma/karma-yoga to arjuna(and the whole world).

In BG 3.12(context for BG 3.14)Bhagwan Sri Krishna is talking about benefits/good-consequences of doing Yagna/Worshipping gods by sacrifices([aka Ishta](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%87%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9F&lang=sans&action=Search)). Bhagwan also points out that the one who does not perform Sacrifices is thief.

> इष्टान्भोगान्हिवोदेवा दास्यन्ते यज्ञ भाविता: ॥
>
> तैर्दत्तान प्रदायेभ्यो यो भुङ्तेस्तेन एव च ॥३.१२॥
>
> In charge of the various necessities of life, the demigods(I prefer gods), **being satisfied by the performance of yajna [sacrifice], will supply all necessities to you**. But he who enjoys such gifts without offering them to the demigods in return is certainly a thief. [BG 3.12](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-3-12/)

**Since Rain is a necessity for life on earth, Gods shower rains as a result of Yagna-karma done by human beings, that's how yagna produces anna or food.**(Yagna -> Rain -> Food).

> अन्नाद्भवन्ति भुतानि पर्जन्याद्न्नसम्भव​:।
>
> यज्ञाद्भवतिपर्जन्यो यज्ञ: कर्मसमुद्भव ॥३.१४॥
>
> All living bodies subsist on food grains, which are produced from rains. Rains are produced by performance of yajna [sacrifice], and yajna is born of prescribed duties. [BG 3.14](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-3-14/)

[Further](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-3-15/) Sri Krishna says that Yagna is born out of karma and karma from Bramhan.

**Point to be noted:**
Yagna means Sacrifice and there are a lot of categories of Yagna. Out of which [Japa yagna is the best one](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-10-23.html). So even Japa yagna helps in sustainment of environment, it is not necessary to do fire rituals.

---

On a side note I would like add some scientific speculation.

Its highly unlikely that the [Ghee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghee) burnt in Agnihotra and Yagnas, would [burn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire)(remember combustion is oxidation reaction consumes oxygen instead of releasing oxygen) and create oxygen to purify atmoshpere.

Comment: This verse already quoted in question

Comment: @RakeshJoshi  What do you mean it's already quoted in question. I am talking about correct interpretation of the verse. So it needs to be quoted again.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of *annam* can be here *vidyà*, *kàla*, *màyà*, *kalà*, *ràga*, *niyati*. All these are *kankukas* whose origin is in *màyà tattva*. **Màyà tattva** is responsible for binding the individual self by creating an illusion of individuality. 
Now the verse can be understood as

> From *annam* which is an undivided object of experience or which is *kankukas* emerge the multitude of creatures. **Annam** comes from **parjanya** who (as the enjoyer of object) is of the nature of consciousness. This is because the objects of enjoyment gain their existence only as a result of their contact with the enjoyer. ***Parjanya*** becomes the enjoyer through sacrifice, which is the act of enjoyment. The act of enjoyment is the result of freedom (*svàtantrya* which is the absolute freedom or autonomy of Shiva responsible for creation) of the *kriyasakti* of **Parmeshvara**.

Thus yajnà is not always physical, it can also be an act of enjoyment full of awareness. E.g, Partaking food while taking our consciousness to the chewing is a Yajna, & sense organs are Demigods.

**Ref: BG by Abhinavgupta**

Comment: but what about physical yajnas ? are they helpful ?

Comment: I don't know whether there will be an established fact in regards of science or not. But it is irrelevant, we can perform this yajnà. :)

Comment: But I am also waiting for an answer for physical yajnà now.